# How to write a JavaScript for loop to iterate what .every and .some methods would do to check an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, methods

I want to create a `for` loop to iterate what `.every` and `.some` methods would do to check an array.

The two Array methods Array.every and Array.some test whether all elements or some elements in an array passes the test callback.

"every" will return true if all elements pass, otherwise it will return false.

"some" will return true as long as one element passes, otherwise it will return false.

I started writing for loops but I don't think they are correct.

Here is what my current code looks like:

```
var every = function (array, test) {
  // Your implementation below
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  const test = array[i]
  console.log(item)
  if (test <= 1) {
   largerThan1 = false
    return 
 }
 return // true or false
 }

 var some = function (array, test) {
  // Your implementation below
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  const test = array[i]
  console.log(item)
  if (test <= 10) {
   largerThan10 = false
   return 
   }
     return // true or false
   }

 var largerThan = function (target) {
  return function (number) {
  return number > target;
  }
  }

  console.log(every([10, 20, 30], largerThan(1)));
   // → true
  console.log(every([10, 20, 30], largerThan(10)));
   // → false
  // console.log(some([10, 20, 30], largerThan(10)));
   // // → true
  // console.log(some([10, 20, 30], largerThan(30)));
  // // → false`
```

Comment: Basically `every` would fail when it first detects a non-conformant value (and the default will be true) and `some` would succeed when it first detects a conformant value (and the default will be false).

Comment: `const test = array[i]` you're overridng your test parameter in each function, so you're discarding the actual testing function (also called the "predicate"). It looks like you're confused about how to actually use the `test` parameter. It's a function, so you call it. Research "first class functions" as a starting point.

Comment: your code does not call the `test` function parameter that's passed in, and on top of that it hides it with a local variable called "test" in the loops.

Comment: What is item?. Also what is largerThan1, largerThan10 variables doing?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the rewritten code using arrow functions.

```js
const every = (array, test) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    const item = array[i];
    if (!test(item)) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}

const some = (array, test) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    const item = array[i];
    if (test(item)) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}

const someArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const largerThanSix = some(someArr, num => num > 6); 

const everyArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const largerThanZero = every(everyArr, num => num > 0);

console.log("Some are larger than 6: ", largerThanSix);
console.log("All of them are larger than 0: ", largerThanZero);
```